# What are the small triangles within the radar?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

There're small triangles, filled and empty ones.

I just came close to the filled one but there's nothing special I see physically.

[image]

What are these?

Comment: Locations marks?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the solid triangle is a location you have discovered, the hollow ones are locations you have not discovered yet. Some locations don't have anything interesting to see.

Answer (score 3):

They do mark places of Interests like User137 said. But they also mark the places where some of the Crazy wasteland perk´s event´s take place. 
**So if you did not have the perk you will not see anything of interest there.**

You should also listen to your Radio while exploring that points.